# Different view of scene with XCode4 and XCode5

Tags: uitableview, ios7, xcode5, space, scene

I created my project in XCode4. In this project I have a scene with a `UITableView` containing a `StaticCell`.

When I compiled the project with XCode5, there is a big space in this scene between the navigation bar and the first cell. How I can remove that space?